# Keras regression model converges to single value for all the input values

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, prediction, recurrent-neural-network

I am using keras regression model to predict the traffic flow on a highway using 5-min traffic flow data. But the model always converges to a single value or predicts the value with very low accuracy. I using eleven 5-min interval flow values, hour(00-23), and sensor id (13 input parameters) to get the approximate flow in last 5-min interval in that hour. I tried to execute the model using different number of epochs (10 to 500) and for different batch sizes (100 - 5000) but no improvement in accuracy. Here is the model I am using for this purpose.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(520, input_dim=13, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(520, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(520, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='normal'))

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=sEpoch, batch_size=sBatch)
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testY)

probabilities = model.predict(predX)
predictions = [float(round(x)) for x in probabilities]
accuracy = np.mean(predictions == predY)
```

I have normalized the input parameters such that their values ranges from 0 to 1 but original values are used as output labels. Sample input data is

```
0.652173913 0.9302192626    0.6422360248    0.6154747948    0.5689045936    0.663003663 0.5816777042    0.6262019231    0.5921052632    0.6151079137    0.5689655172    0.623501199 0.6451204056
0.652173913 0.931508202 0.5763975155    0.5486518171    0.5630153121    0.5836385836    0.5143487859    0.5625  0.5120614035    0.5755395683    0.5666666667    0.5887290168    0.6172370089
0.652173913 0.9315030047    0.5763975155    0.5486518171    0.5630153121    0.5836385836    0.5143487859    0.5625  0.5120614035    0.5755395683    0.5666666667    0.5887290168    0.6172370089
```

The corresponding output labels are

```
522
475
475
```

How can I get correct prediction values?

Comment: Start with not using accuracy in regression, and to normalize both inputs and outputs. Also put a sigmoid activation at the output.

Comment: What do you mean by not using accuracy in regression? What is its impact on model training?

Comment: No impact, accuracy is only defined for classification, with regression you will most likely get zero accuracy, which will only confuse you.

Comment: Fine. As mentioned in your first comment, I added sigmoid in output and normalized the output as well. Now loss value is very low (less than 1) but if we check the predicted values, it is generating only zeors.

Comment: Less than one is not "very low". What is the actual range of unnormalized output values? Seems the network is not learning anything, so the problem is way more complex than for a SO question.

Comment: Actual output values range from 0 to 850. Yes, it is not low. As it was around 0.16% with normalized output and is around 330 with the unnormalized output data. Predicted values converges to single value in either case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148732/discussion-between-qazi-and-matias-valdenegro).

Comment: I would request you to post this question here [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @quintumnia, posted there as well.

Comment: @Qazi That's cool

Comment: Why do you have 520 nodes in first hidden Layer? Maybe reduce the size of the network for only 13 input nodes

Comment: Also you output layer for regression should be linear